# Receiving a 'Submit Failed' error when trying to make changes to API configuration

Tags: google-api, chatbot, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I have made a simple bot for Google Chat, which has been working perfectly fine for the past couple of weeks. I tried to make a change to the API configuration for Hangouts Chat, and am greeted by this error.

[image: Image of Error]

I have tried making different changes to the API, and receive the error every time. Even simple things such as disabling the bot status gives me the same issue.

I tried re-making the project from scratch, as well as trying a different account on the same domain. The issue persists.

Comment: Upper right hand corner should have a feed back button.  Its probably a bug

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related its a bug in an application probably better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaImTo Have used the feedback button previous to posting this question. But was hoping it was something related to what I was doing. Will post over at Webapps in-case